# ActionScript 3 .replace() only replaces first instance

Tags: string, actionscript-3

In Flash ActionScript 3, I am trying to do something I thought was simple: replace all instances of a phrase in a text string with another phrase. However, for some reason only the first instance is replaced and the rest ignored. I hacked a solution together by running it through the string replace function around 9 times so the end result has all the `<br />` replaced but I'd like to know what I've done wrong. Thanks in advance!

My Code:

```
var importPostAddress = "123 Fake Street<br />Mytown<br />Mycounty<br />Mycountry<br />PO5 7CD<br /><br />";
var postAddress = importPostAddress.replace("<br />",", ");
```

Expected result when tracing `postAddress`:

```
123 Fake Street, Mytown, Mycounty, Mycountry, PO5 7CD, ,
```

Actual result:

```
123 Fake Street, Mytown<br />Mycounty<br />Mycountry<br />PO5 7CD<br /><br />
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In order to fix this, you need to do juuuust a little bit more work.

```
var importPostAddress = "123 Fake Street<br />Mytown<br />Mycounty<br />Mycountry<br />PO5 7CD<br /><br />";
var pattern:RegExp = /<br \/>/g;
var postAddress = importPostAddress.replace(pattern,", ");
```

I'm using a `RegExp` in order to pass the **/g** flag, which makes the replacement **global** (replace all instances of the expression found). I also had to escape the `/` in `<br />` using a backslash `\`, as its a control character in regular expressions.

Comment: Hi Sam thanks for your reply. Do you use `/` instead of quotes for defining a string?? Does this effectively say: `var pattern:RegExp = "<br \/>"g;` ? or `"<br \/>"/g;`

Comment: @CraigMcArthur You use `/` instead of quotes for defining a `RexExp`. This basically says replace the pattern (in this case the pattern has no special regex characteristics, so it's practically a String) `<br />` **globally**.

Answer (score 22):

Sam has a good solution, another one is:

```
postAddress = importPostAddress.split("<br />").join(",");
```

Comment: For me this is the only solution, **for** it's a pain in the ... to replace all strings that are **not hard-coded** into your code with RegExp. Maybe I want to replace `n`, maybe `backslash` or maybe the **user** wants to enter random characters that I need to remove from the strings.